# How do I get the user object from Django middleware?

Tags: python, django

I have the following middleware:

```
class TestMiddleware():
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        print(getattr(request, "user", None))
        return self.get_response(request)
```

The `print` function always prints `None`. I added the middleware both before and after the `django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware` line in settings.py, but in either case, I get `None`. Also, I'm logged in as a user.

What else can I try? I'm using Django 1.11.

Comment: Yeah I tried that originally, but I replaced it with `getattr` for debugging purposes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your middleware should be after `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` if you want to access the user. You don't need to use `getattr`, just `request.user` should work. Depending on whether you are logged in or not, it will be the logged-in user or an [`AnonymousUser`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#anonymoususer-object).

Comment: Okay, when I put my middleware after `AuthenticationMiddleware`, it worked, even though I'm pretty sure I tried exactly that before. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I also putted it after `'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware'` and it doesn't work. `request.user.is_authenticated` always returns False even if the user is logged in. I use Django 3.0.

Comment: @zshanabek please ask a new question and include your code, I can’t help you in the comments.

Comment: I'm using my middleware in the end , or just after the AuthenticationMiddleware  , but all I get is a 'AnonymousUser'

Comment: @kommradHomer as I said above please ask a new question, I can’t help you in the comments.